# Mantendo padrão de criação ComplexType no EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Antigamente eu utilizava o Entity Framework 6.0, e ao criar uma classe como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class Produto {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string NomeProduto { get; set; }
    public atributo atributo { get; set; }
}

public class atributo {
    public string peso { get; set; }
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
}
```

Meu BD era criado somente uma tabela, Produtos:

com as colunas

- ProdutoId
- NomeProduto
- atributo_peso
- atributo_valor

Porém, ao utilizar o EF Core, ele cria duas tabelas, Produtos e atributos, e vincula o atributo com uma FK na tabela produtos. Eu compreendo esse comportamento, porém, gostaria de manter o padrão antigo, como era no EF 6.0.

Alguém sabe como posso configurar dessa forma?

**EDIT**

Como foi dito pelo nosso colega @HudsonPH poderia herdar atributos em Produtos.  Mas digamos que eu tenha varias classes para utilizar como propriedades em **Produtos**, eu teria que ficar herdando varias classes? Outra coisa minha ideia é que, quando eu for programar outras partes do sistema, eu utilize, **produto.atributo.peso** e não **produto.peso**. eu fiz um exemplo simples na pergunta, mas meus modelos reais são bem mais complexos

**EDIT 2**

[Encontrei a solução](https://medium.com/@fabiogemignani/mapeando-entidades-de-valor-no-entity-framework-core-2-7c1dc17b0134), basta adicionar o seguinte método a sua classe contexto

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {   
            modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>()
                .OwnsOne<atributo>(s => s.atributo);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mapear Object value no Entity Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285276/mapear-object-value-no-entity-core)

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma:

```
public class Produto : atributo {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string NomeProduto { get; set; }
}

public class atributo {
    public string peso { get; set; }
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
}
```

Mas a primeira forma que vc fez estava errada, porque era para ter criado 2 tabelas tambem.

Comment: O problema é que eu tenho varias propriedades como essa **atributos**, ai eu teria que herdar varias classes....

Comment: nao tem problem herda de base class, o codigo fica organizado e facil de fazer manutecao, de outra maneira vc so vai gera mais e mais funcoes para fazer operacoes basicas pq o seu modelo que vc quer nao se encaixa no EF

Comment: [Exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: C# não suporta herança de várias classes, como o cenário que o @BrunoHenri descreveu. Uma possibilidade é a utilização de interfaces no cenário, mas ainda assim isso não previne conflito de nomes.

Comment: Nao sei como voce chegou nessa conclusao de confilito de nomes, mas voce pode ter UMA BASE CLASS e o resto interface, fazer uma solucao usando EF so deixa o codigo escravo do EF @OnoSendai

Comment: @HudsonPH Assuma uma classe, `ClasseTeste`, que implementa duas interfaces ao mesmo tempo: `IInterfaceA` e `IInterfaceB`. As duas especificam uma propriedade com o mesmo nome, `Valor`.  Em C# você pode utilizar implementações explícitas; o EF Core (mencionado pelo AP) aparentemente possui problemas com isso (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3790, https://readerman1.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/ef-context-explicit-interface-implementation-raises-an-exception/).

Comment: mas nao estou sugerindo implementacao de interface e sim base class

Comment: A menção ao conflito de nomes foi relativa à utilização de interfaces, o que seria uma alternativa viável de implementação compatível com as espectativas do EF Core.

Comment: o que voce esta falando esta correto mas nao se aplica na minha solucao, se existe 10 classes que precisao ter 2 campos iguais (peso e valor) a melhor solucao e a criacao de uma baseclass para esse problema

Comment: qual a vantagem de ter essa baseclass, voce nao precisa escrever uma funcao para cada entity voce pode fazer uma unica onde T é sua baseclass