# Mapear Object value no Entity Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Eu tenho a classe

```
public class Email  
{
     public string Endereco { get; }
     public string  NomeExibicao{ get; }
}
```

Estou tentando mapear no EF Core usando o seguinte código

```
 builder.Property(e => e.Email.Endereco)
            .HasColumnName("EmailUsuario");
```

Quando tento executar o update aparece a mensagem :

> The expression 'e => e.Email.Endereco' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.
>   Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression

No EF 6 funcionava direitinho.

Os outros mapeamentos da mesma Entidade estão funcionando.

Comment: Compartilhe o código que você faz o update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mapear no [Entity Framework Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) é diferente, o recurso utilizado é [Tipos de propriedades (Owned types)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities), ***um exemplo básico para a sua pergunta***:

As duas Entidades:

```
public class People
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Email Email { get; set; }
}
public class Email  
{
     public string Endereco { get; set; }
     public string NomeExibicao { get; set; }
}
```

Configuração `Fluent`:

```
builder.ToTable("People")
    .OwnsOne(x => x.Email, x =>
    {
        x.Property(a => a.Endereco)
            .HasColumnName("Endereco")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        x.Property(a => a.NomeExibicao)
            .HasColumnName("NomeExibicao")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    });
```

Como nessa configuração não foi estabelecida a **tabela** que poderia ser gravado esses dados os mesmo pertence automaticamente a **tabela** `People` como [explicado na documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#storing-owned-types-in-separate-tables)

**People**

```
Id
Name
Endereco
NomeExibicao
```

***Referencias***

- [Owned Entity Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)
- [Entity Framework Core Quick Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)
- [Storing owned types in separate tables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#storing-owned-types-in-separate-tables)